# Loop through specific columns in dataframe

Tags: r, algorithm, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to loop through, printing out the values from each dataframe... I'm new to R and am more familiar with python and javascript so I'm gonna pseudo-code what I'm trying to say here:

```
df <- read.table(text="
              a     b    c    d     e      f       g
              1     5    6    7     3      4       7
              3     2    8    4     1      9       4
              6     5    2    5     4      6       1
         ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

my javascript mentality...(I only want to select from columns 4 and on):

```
for (i = 3; i < df.length; i++) {
     console.log(i)
}
```

and it would return to me

```
              d     e      f       g
              7     3      4       7
              4     1      9       4
              5     4      6       1
```

to understand this better, I'm making a dashboard where when I hover over certain data points only values from certain columns are being displayed in a tooltip, which is why i still need to keep the original dataframe without shortening it, yet write an algorithm that will return values from specific columns in the dataframe just for the tooltip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two different ways two subset a dataframe:

```
# by column numbers
df[, 4:7]

# by column names
names <- c("d", "e", "f", "g")
df[names]
```

Comment: i need to subset everything after the 3rd row. how do i do that? I tried `df[, 4:]` and `df[, 4:nrow(df)]` with no luck

Comment: try `df[, 4:ncol(df)]` or `df[, 4:length(df)]`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: you only don't need the first 3. you can also do `df[,-(1:3)]`

Comment: Onyambu's worked but it actually turns out I also need to drop the last two, so how do I add that in now without selecting specific columns? Reason being is because the number of columns between the 4th up until the last two may vary...

Comment: @Onyambu answer does the exact same subsetting as the solution that I supplied based on your reproducible example. `drop <- -c((1:3), c(dim(df)[2], dim(df)[2]-1)); df[, drop]`

Comment: `df[,-c(1:3,6,7)]`

Comment: @roarkz It did for this example but I don't want to select columns 4:7 I want to REMOVE columns 1:3 which is what Onyambu did. Also the first time I tried your ncol(df) it didn't work but now it's working which means i must've done something wrong.. embarrasing :'(

Answer (score 0):

Try this: df[,c(3,4,5,6)]

And check out this link: https://dzone.com/articles/learn-r-how-extract-rows

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking.

Comment: almost, I need everything after the 3rd column. I don't want to specify exactly which ones

Answer (score 0):

You can run a loop over with a conditional to loop:

```
for (column in dataFrame) {
if(column %% 2 == 0){
for (entry in rawdata[,column]) {
#run your code here, it will impact ever second column
  }
 }
}
```

Change the 0 to a 1 in order to do it for every odd column.